# Kernel upgrade lubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, kernel, lubuntu

How often does system upgrades the kernel? Should I do it manually? 
I have ubuntu 14.04.2 and it has kernel version 3.16, and lubuntu from minimal install 14.04.2 with kernel 3.13, so I wondered why it don't upgrade kernel at least to 3.16?

Is there any PPA for kernel update because ppa:kernel-ppa/ppa doesn`t work?

Comment: Any reason to update?

Answer (score 2):

Like most software in Ubuntu, the major version shipped (eg 3.13, 3.16, 3.19) is maintained for as long as that version of Ubuntu works. Security fixes are applied and pushed out through Apt.

Maintaining software rather than just upgrading everything  is a *feature* of Ubuntu.

That said, if you really need a later version, there are options:

- LTS releases can hop to the non-LTS versions of the kernel by installing the HWE stacks. You're actually already using one of these (they come bundled in the LTS point releases) but you can upgrade to the Vivid version by installing `linux-generic-lts-vivid`. [See more about this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack).
- "The Kernel PPA" isn't a PPA in the sense of Launchpad-hosted, Apt-compatible PPAs. It's just a file-dump of built kernel packages. [You can browse it here](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/).

  **Note:** These do not have Ubuntu patches applied and your system will not automatically upgrade if and when security-patched versions are made available. **You will have to upgrade manually**.
- Build it yourself. [It isn't hard](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile); it just looks hard. As above, you're in charge of keeping on top of security advisories and applying updates.

But yeah, if you're happy on 3.16, stay on 3.16.

Comment: Thx, for reply. But I didn`t catch why the same *buntu has different kernels? I have red that kernel 4.1 came out with a lot of improvements, do u think is there reason to upgrade to it?

Comment: Note that e.g. upgrading to kernel 4.x (from 3.x) might include changes that ends up breaking software you have installed. This is of course dependent on what features the various software packages depend on. Doing updates blindly - just because it is available - might not always be painless. Example: running the Nvidia proprietary driver.